# What is the Quota limit of Youtube API now?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, quota

**I know since April 2016 the default Quota limit of Youtube API is 1M.**

If we want to increase it, we need to **send a request to Google**.

I wonder what is the maximum value of Quota limit that we can require?

Answer (score 2):

As per google developer console it will allow certain limit for Apis.

You can check out in your google console by enabling the youtube api and you will see the screen below

[Here i mentioned screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uxDj.png)

Comment: I know. But it is not I want. We can ask Google to increase the quota limit. I want to know the maximum value that we can ask Google to increase.